# Error - PHP Warning: Undefined array key "gid"

Tags: arrays, switch-statement, key, warnings

Does anyone know how to fix this error, please? PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "gid" in /index.php

[index.php]

```
$gid = ['1245620'];
$mid = ['0111161];
$sid = ['0108778];

switch($_GET['gid']) {
    case '1': 
        echo "1 selected!;
    break;

    case '2': 
        echo "2 selected!;
    break;

    default:
        header("Location: http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];");
}

switch($_GET['mid']) {
    case '1': 
        echo "1 selected!;
    break;

    case '2': 
        echo "2 selected!;
    break;

    default:
        header("Location: http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];");
}

switch($_GET['sid']) {
    case '1': 
        echo "1 selected!;
    break;

    case '2': 
        echo "2 selected!;
    break;

    default:
        header("Location: http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];");
}
```

Should return on browser index.php?gid=1, index.php?mid=1, index.php?sid=1 but it returns me to default with an error in the error_log file (stated above.

Could it be due to me using three switches in one file (index.php)?

Any help please, it's giving me such an headache?

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined array key "gid"

This means there were not GET variables passed with ‘gif’ as the key.

Try debugging `var_dump($_GET)` to make sure any arguments are being passed. If not, check your Nginx/Apache config.

You will also wish to wrap the switches with an `if` statement to check [isset($_GET[‘gid’])](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is set before checking in the switch.